# How to access tuple's elements in a class that inherits it

Tags: python, tuples

Suppose I'm trying to write a class that acts like a tuple in every way except one: when you `print` it, any values above 10 are replaced by 10. I would usually do this by having a class that inherits tuple but changing the `__str__` magic method. However, I do not know how tuple's `__str__` magic method is written so I'm unsure of how I can access each individual element to check if it is above 10 to print it.

Are there any solutions to this (if its relevant, each of these tuples will only have two fields)?

```
class sampleClass(tuple):

    def __str__(self):
        return "({0}, {1})".format(min(elem1IsomehowGet, 10), min(elem2IsomehowGet, 10))
```

```
>>> x = sampleClass((3, 15))
>>> print x
(3, 10)
>>> x[1]
15
```

Comment: I added some, but I'm not sure how useful it is.

Comment: Are replaced by `'H'`? You replace it with a `10`.

Comment: Tuples are containers and when they're printed they iterate over their contents and call each item's `__repr__()` method. I think a better approach would be to populate the tuple with objects which are instances of some custom class you've created that has its own `__repr__` that does what you want.

Comment: To answer your question, though, just use `self[index]` in a method (or call `self.__getitem__(index)`). The value returned will be the item at that index in the tuple subclass instance.

Comment: Thank you, I think I was really looking for the self[index] thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
class sampleClass:
    def __init__(self, tup):
            self.tup = tup
    def __str__(self): #To print it
            return str(tuple([item if item <= 10 else 10 for item in self.tup])) #List comprehension to replace x > 10 with 10, then convert to a tuple, then surround with quotes so __str__ accepts it
    def __getitem__(self, ind): #To access by index e.g. x[1], x[-1] etc.
            return self.tup[ind]
```

---

```
>>> from sampleClass import sampleClass as sc
>>> x = sc((3, 15))
>>> x[1]
15
>>> print x
(3, 10)
>>>
```

<sup>Note: I replaced all values greater than 10 with `'H'`, which is what you *wrote* in your question, however, in your question
                                                                                 you replaced it with a 10.</sup>



                                                         <sup>Note: JK, you edited your question</sup>
                            [image]

Comment: Thanks - Yeah, I got mixed up between what I wanted, but that makes sense.

Comment: :) no problem, it happens